# Refreshing token with Hybrid Flow

Tags: asp.net, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I'm sure I'm missing something.

I have an MVC app & an SSO site that uses Thinktecture Identity Server. The MVC app use hybrid flow to authenticate users on the SSO site. The MVC site uses the Microsoft OpenIdConnect OWIN client to talk to SSO. My tokens have quite a short lifespan - about 5 mins, but I have refresh tokens so the user is constantly re-authenticated. This is a quite useful feature.

However when the token needs refreshing, the user is bounced via the SSO site, which breaks form posts, ajax calls, etc. This is less useful.

Can I not do this renewal on the server, rather than having the user-agent do it? I can't see a way to do this.

I'm also about to look into sliding expiration to try to solve this problem, although I'd been lead to believe sliding expiration was a bad think from a security point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing something. I was getting confused about who was responsible for various activities.

The user should be bounced via the SSO site when their token has expired. I now have sliding expiration on the cookie with an absolute time limit. Ideally this limit should correspond with the expiration of the tokens, but I have a refresh token, so that could be used to refresh the tokens from the server.

Once the relying party has received a valid response, it is responsible for keeping the user logged in, not the SSO site. The SSO site can be used once the tokens need refreshing.